# Pass a single row query to a stored procedure's parameters in the shortest way

Tags: t-sql

I could do it with a cursor, but I wonder is there any other way to do it?

for example a query

```
select a, b, c
from query 
where id = 1
```

pass to a stored procedure (that can't be changed) in the shortest way + without using a cursor, and change the value of "a" column

```
proc test_sp
@a int,
@b int,
@c int
as

select @a + a + 1
from test
where b = @b and c = @c
```

so, the ideal would be something like this:

```
select
(
    exec test_sp @a = a, @b = b, @c = c
    from query 
    where id = 1
) a, b, c
from query 
where id = 1
```

But of course, it will not work. So, is there any other way to do it?

And please note that the procedure can't be changed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? What is the objective ?

Comment: It looks to me like you just need a simple `table-valued function`.

Comment: @Squirrel the procedure has a specific logic that will return corrected values and I have to run it against a set of data

Comment: @KekuSemau as I replied to Squirrel I am looking for the shortest way to pass values from a query to the proc that will correct one variable and return in back

Comment: @DejanDozet at the moment I can only give you this hint for further reading. TVFs (Tables-valued functions) are basicly Views with parameters that can consist of mutliple statements if needed, and unlike SPs they can be directly used with other tables (via join/apply) in the FROM-part.

Comment: @KekuSemau, thanks that is a good idea, let me see if I can adapt my procedure that way

Answer (score 0):

If you know the amount and types of parameters beforehand, I'd say the easiest solution would be to create a procedure that takes a table name as parameter, and dynamically reads it into a local table, which you can then use to do anything.

```
create proc test_sp
@tablename nvarchar(128)
as begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    set @sql=N'select * from ['+@tablename+']'
    create table #t
    (
        -- define same columns as your "query"
    )
    insert #t
        exec(@sql)
        
    -- now do whatever you want to your #t
end -- proc
```

So then you would save your query into a table, and then call the proc, like:

```
select a, b, c
into ##a
from query 
where id = 1

exec test_sp '##a'
```

Notice in this example that, if you use #tables, you have to use a double-hash else the dynamic sql won't be able to access it.

The better-structured way to do this is to use a table parameter, but it's a bit more aggravating due to having to define a new table type in the db, so I prefer the first way for semi-permanent stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't change the procedure, it has a specific logic and it's used by many other sections of code.

Comment: Ah, sorry but no, then. It's either cursor or change your proc to use set logic, eitherthrough table parameters or a table name parameter.